# Spring Security - Get Credentials returns null

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have a springboot app, using ActiveDirectory for authentication. I intent to use login credentials for further querying the AD. Unfortunately the getCredentials() method return null.

My Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new AppUserDetailsContextMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                        env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.domain"),
                        env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.urls")
                );
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider())
                .eraseCredentials(false)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(
                Collections
                        .singletonList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider())
        );
    }

}
```

I intent to use these details for further querying the AD using details of the currently logged in user as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSource authenticationSource(){
        return new SpringSecurityAuthenticationSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setReferral("follow");
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.urls"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.base"));
        contextSource.setAuthenticationSource(authenticationSource());
        return contextSource;
    }
```

But on accessing the loggedIn user, getcredentials returns null

```
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(authentication.getCredentials()); // null result
```